# Apache Solr facet search exclude space

Tags: php, solr, facet

I am using Apache Solr and using following Query for search

```
http://Siteurl:8080/solr/metro/select?q=*:*&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=Make
```

But as result let suppose I have 'Ford Fiesta' in make field. I am getting two results instead of one as shown below :

```
Ford => 21
Fiesta => 21
```

It is seprating field by space.

I want it like

```
Ford Fiesta => 21
```

Please let me know the valid method to do so.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Guys 

I sort this out myself. In Schema.xml file I only need to set Make field type as String which was previously added as text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is very simple here. You are trying to facet on tokenized field (text). This means each token will be counted separately. I suggest you to add new field (in schema.xml file) which you will feed with the same data as field `Make` (eg. using copy field). This new field should be string or text with KeywordTokenizer.

Please look at the example below. I added there two types: string and text_not_tokenized. Then defined two fields Make_string and Make_nonTokenized. When you facet on each of them you should see "Ford Fiesta"

So you can just query

```
http://Siteurl:8080/solr/metro/select?q=*:*&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=Make_string
```

or

```
http://Siteurl:8080/solr/metro/select?q=*:*&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=Make_nonTokenized
```

.

```
...
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
<fieldType name="text_not_tokenized" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
...
<field name="Make_string" type="string">
<field name="Make_nonTokenized" type="text_not_tokenized">
....
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I followed the same approach and it worked.